Finding Text of Negotiations for Biodiversity Convention
I'm currently reading the Biodiversity Convention (CBD) 1992 and came across this passage:

"The Contracting Parties, Conscious of the intrinsic value of
biological diversity and of the ecological, genetic, social, economic,
scientific, educational, cultural, recreational and aesthetic values
of biological diversity and its components..."

I'm curious to know how the contracting parties reached this understanding of the intrinsic value of biological diversity. To do that, I need the text of their negotiation process before the final text was agreed upon. I've searched online but couldn't find it. Could anyone help me find it?

Is there good reason to think that the negotiations were committed to writing in some official way? Media reports might be the only source.

@ohwilleke I think they're looking for what are known as the "travaux préparatoires" or "preparatory work." Art. 32 of the Vienna Convention says that this material may be of supplementary use in interpretation. The UN library points to a few potential sources of this preparatory or other related material (United Nations, Dag Hammarskjöld Library, "What are travaux préparatoires and how can I find them?"). Whether it's actual available for a given treaty is highly variable.
